# Geometric fundamentals of a variable

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1I7T.png)

Hi, first post on here. Sorry this seems like a basic question compared to other posts.

As seen in this graph manipulations of ${x}$ take different paths approaching ${x}$. Are the geometric shapes fundamental to the operations? I’m really trying to get a good core understanding.

Edit for clarity:

Before all points meet at (1, 1) the lines approaching (1, 1) are different. If I use the coordinates (0, y to 0, 1), (0, x to 1) and (1, 1) as a frame of reference I can see that each function relates to a different shape within that frame of reference as x is approaching 1.

Context:

I’m looking at patterns in irrational numbers and their geometric operations. Looking at ${x^2}$ for instance; is this curve a rotation or completely linear fundamentally and curved when concatenated with an exponential function?

I’m not a mathematician so it’s very hard to speak the language fluent enough to get my question across effectively.

Comment: What operations? What does it mean for a geometric shape to be fundamental to an operation?

Comment: You have to give ${x}$ a value which is an operation in itself

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning and the more I read it the less I do.

Comment: If x always reaches 1 and I use an operation like raising ${x}$ to a power it relates a different shape on this graph which is on the picture link. The shapes are different shapes yet they all reach 1 and the only difference is what I’m doing to ${x}$ I’m sorry I can’t provide more clarity than that. Thanks

Comment: You have a bunch of functions that all include the point (1, 1). But it's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: Was this question generated by an AI?

Comment: @G.Fougeron Now, now, be nice. Their English is better than my Finnish, or my Mandarin, or my machine language for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to see exactly what you are asking, but here is my attempt:

The shape of $y=x^2$ is a parabola.  Parabolas all have the same general shape: symmetrical, open at one end, a single extremum (max or min value) and extending to infinity in the other direction.  The most general parabola can be written $y = ax^2 + bx + c$.  It is called a conic section.

The functions you are considering, except for $x^x$ which is a special case, are called power functions.  A power function generally is $y = a x^k$.  If the power is $k > 1$ then the function rises faster and faster.  If the power is $k < 1$ then it rises slower and slower as $x$ increases moving to the right.  The larger $k$ is, the more sharply it curves upward.

An irrational exponent is generally defined as the limit of rational exponents that approach it.  So $x^1, x^{1.4}, x^{1.41}, x^{1.414},...$ are functions that approach $x^{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean. Thank you so much!